# Use data from one collection in another collection Firestore Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Hello everyone, I explain, I have 2 Collections.

1 Post

2 Users

In the Users collection, I have another Collection called Favorite

What I want to create is a favorites tab, where the user can click on the typical heart button and the post that he has added to favorites is added to favorites.

What occurred to me was that by clicking the favorite button, the ID of the document of the post is stored to the user. That is already programmed. What I don't know is how to use the data stored in the favorites collection, to filter it in the Post collection and only show me in that tab the posts that the user has added to favorites.

I have the following code to bring the data of the favorite collection.

```
myRef.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                        list.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        System.out.println("Rew es: "+ list.toString());
```

With the following code I receive a list of the entire collection that the user has saved, the detail is that I don't know how to use it in the query that will show me the information.

```
Query query = mFirestore.collection("Post")
                        ;

                        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<activos> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<activos>()
                                .setQuery(query, activos.class).build();
```

I'm not sure if the entire collection needs to be brought in, or if it can be item by item. I'm really stuck here a bit.

I also don't know if it's the best way to implement the favorites tab that way.

Also as a curious fact, I have placed as the ID of the favorite collection document, the ID of the post saved, and in the field saved as the favorite ID, I have also placed the ID of the POST.

Thanks in advance for the help, I leave the complete code for you to check

Do you think this is the best way to do the favorites activity?

or have any other suggestions ...

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: Hi alex, Done, screenshots added

Comment: Please also add the content of your `activos` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
mRef.orderByChild("idFromFireBase").equalTo("idLike").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {list.clear;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                list.add(datas.getValue(Favorite.class);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, keys, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Should work!!
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Phong, I use the cloud firestore database